# How can I list the dependency tree of a catkin package?

Tags: catkin, rosdep, rospack, rosws, wstool

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am [installing](http://www.ros.org/wiki/groovy/Installation/Raspbian/Source) ROS from source on a raspberry pi, which has worked well so far.

I have ros_comm built and can launch roscore, which is wonderful. I want to build joystick_drivers next and here lies the problem: Is there a way to automatically download the source for the unmet ROS package dependency tree for the package I'm trying to install. Is this even possible? Or do I need to keep hitting catkin_make and fix build errors one at a time?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54878/how-can-i-list-the-dependency-tree-of-a-catkin-package?/) by [Dereck](https://answers.ros.org/users/2254/dereck/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1070 on 2013-02-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dereck,

You can have the dependency generated online

```
cd catkin_ws/src
wstool merge http://packages.ros.org/web/rosinstall/generate/raw/groovy/joystick_drivers
```

You can replace joystick_drivers with any ROS package. It will resolve the full tree but will only merge the missing packages into your source folder. Do no forget to

```
wstool update
```

once you merged all packages

Kai

---

Originally posted by [kalectro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3904/kalectro/) with karma: 1554 on 2013-02-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dereck](https://answers.ros.org/users/2254/dereck/) on 2013-02-11**:
Perhaps I'm not setting up my workspace correctly, because that command pulled in every dependency including things I already built. I built and installed ros_comm and it's dependencies in '/opt/ros/groovy' and then created a new workspace with 'wstool init ~/ws/src /opt/ros/groovy'

**Comment by [kalectro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3904/kalectro/) on 2013-02-11**:
there is no need to create a new workspace. Go to the src folder where all the ros core packages are in and wstool merge the new ones. That should only pull the new packages

**Comment by [Dereck](https://answers.ros.org/users/2254/dereck/) on 2013-02-11**:
Thanks for updating the wiki, I'm giving it a rundown on an rpi right now.  BTW, is it possible to use overlays with your method? I would like to avoid rebuilding everything each time I add a package to my system.

**Comment by [kalectro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3904/kalectro/) on 2013-02-11**:
If you want to use overlays, you do not need to merge the new sources, just initialize wstool with the link:
wstool init src http://packages.ros.org/web/rosinstall/generate/raw/groovy/joystick_drivers